# Youtube data api search not returning nextpagetoken?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I've tried both youtube data api search and playlist and pagetoken isn't returned, no matter the channel id

```
      $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='.$playlist_id.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$api_key;
            

            $curl = curl_init($url);

                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

                curl_close($curl);

                $responseObj = json_decode($json_response);
                $returned_videos =  $responseObj->items;

print_r($returned_videos);
```

An object is returned with: kind,etag,id,snippet but no nextpagetoken?

I also try search and also no nextpagetoken returned.

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channel_id.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$api_key;
```

How do i solve?

example response

```
 stdClass Object
    (
        [kind] => youtube#playlistItem
        [etag] => bIj6gaNGAK58y5K2z7H6AbPfNBE
        [id] => VVVCU2pPYjM3U3c5elJUOVRhS3o4eFVnLjU2QjQ0RjZEMTA1NTdDQzY=
        [snippet] => stdClass Object
            (
         )
   )
```

Comment: Hm, according to documentation, it should always give you a nextPageToken, when the request is sucessfull. Can you post an example response you're getting?

Comment: i've added example response(i didn't include snippet object data).  The channel has 200+ videos.  I've tried with other channels and nextpagetoken isn't returned?

Comment: Is the response you posted the `$responseObj` or one of the Items?

Comment: thanks!! smh, i should of seen this earlier.